# Dataproc Spark Job sometimes gets java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for iceberg jar file

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-iceberg

The dataproc cluster creation and spark job submission are scheduled every hour then the cluster will be deleted after the job completed. Sometimes the job is failed due to

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions

The jar package is configured with cluster properties:

```
"properties": {
                "dataproc:pip.packages": "google-cloud-secret-manager==2.15.0",
                "spark:spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.3.0",
                "spark:spark.sql.extensions": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions",
                "spark:spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog",
                "spark:spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type": "hive" }
```

Sometimes resubmitting the job succeeds, but other times it still gets the same error so I have to recreate the cluster.
Is there any way to stop the `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: Hi @suisen, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: hi @kiranmathew I've posted this issue on the issue tracker as you suggested, almost a week and there wasn't any responds yet. do you have any idea at least what caused this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` to happen randomly from time to time?

Comment: Hey @suisen, you'll get a faster response if you create a ticket [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/). It's hard to address your issue without knowing the root cause. I've seen a similar [error](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/6266).